# Swift JSON Parsing Error?

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, swifty-json

I am trying to use swifty son to parse a local file. I am able to store content in data, but for some reason using JSON from the swift son framework is not storing any content (And number of rows is counting 0). What am I doing wrong?

```
import SwiftyJSON
class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var NumberofRows = 0
    var names = [String]()

    func parseJSON(){
    let path =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("documents", withExtension: "json")

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: path!) as NSData!

    let readableJSON = JSON(data: data)


    NumberofRows = readableJSON["Documents"].count

    print(NumberofRows)

    for i in 1...NumberofRows {
        var doc = "Doc" + "\(i)"
        var Name = readableJSON["Documents"][doc]["name"].string as String!
        names.append(Name)
    }

}
```

Comment: in your code data is not null when you run your code?

Comment: What happens when you try to `print(readableJSON)`?

Comment: @ConnorNeville it prints "null"

Comment: @ReinierMelian how do I tell if the core data is null or not?

Comment: Verify that "documents.json" is in the root directory of your project, and that it contains valid JSON. This is telling you that SwiftyJSON wasn't able to find valid JSON at that URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yu need to check whether NSData is null or not.

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("documents", withExtension: "json") {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: path) as? NSData {
        let readableJSON = JSON(data: data)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: If `data` is `nil` the developer is supposed to do his homework ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I have misunderstood the comments to your question. Are you sure the JSON is correct?